How and where to store the progress of each player in a game like Hamster Kombat in Telegram?
I want to make a game in Telegram like Hamster Kombat, I’m doing it in node.js (typescript), I’m wondering how the developers of Hamster, for example, stored the players’ progress, a database comes to mind, but I want to understand exactly how to store it.
I asked GPT, GPT said that it is possible to store progress in a smart contract, I have not dealt with smart contracts and therefore I am not sure that this is possible. Who can tell me I will be grateful
I tried to make a smart contract and some kind of nonsense, nothing worked and I began to believe less that this was being done in a smart contract. help)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Storing players’ progress for a game like Hamster Kombat typically involves using a database.
Using smart contracts for this purpose is technically possible but generally impractical for several reasons:
Why a Database Makes Sense
Flexibility: Databases (like PostgreSQL, MongoDB, etc.) are well-suited for managing dynamic data, such as game progress, inventory, and achievements.
Performance: They are faster and more efficient for frequent updates, which are typical in games.
Cost: Storing and updating data in a blockchain can be expensive because of transaction fees.
When Smart Contracts Might Be Used
Smart contracts are more suitable for storing high-value, immutable data (e.g., ownership of rare in-game items as NFTs). However, for routine player progress, they introduce unnecessary complexity and cost.
Suggested Approach
Use a Database: For player stats, achievements, inventory, and other progress, use a database. You could also implement a caching layer (e.g., Redis) for faster access.
Integrate Blockchain for Special Features (Optional): If your game has unique, tradeable items or achievements that need to be decentralized, store them on a blockchain using a smart contract, but only for those specific features.
Steps to Store Player Progress and Integrate the Game with Telegram
Database Design:
Create tables or collections for:
Players: Store user IDs, usernames, and other metadata.
Progress: Store levels, achievements, and scores.
Inventory: Store in-game items, if any.
Example schema for a NoSQL database like MongoDB:
{
  "userId": "123456",
  "username": "PlayerOne",
  "progress": {
    "level": 10,
    "score": 1500,
    "achievements": ["First Win", "Sharpshooter"]
  },
  "inventory": ["Sword", "Shield"]
}

Backend API:
Develop API endpoints using Node.js (TypeScript):
GET /progress/
: Fetch a player's progress.
POST /progress: Update a player's progress.
GET /inventory/
: Fetch a player's inventory.
POST /inventory: Update a player's inventory.
Example: Use Express.js for building the API.
Optimization:
Use Redis for caching frequently accessed data (e.g., leaderboard).
Implement indexing on user IDs or other frequently queried fields.
Security:
Use JWT tokens or Telegram's bot token-based user authentication for secure communication.
Encrypt sensitive data before storing it.
Telegram Bot Integration:
Create a Telegram Bot:
Use BotFather to create a bot and get the token.
Connect the Bot to Your App:
Use a library like telegraf to interact with the Telegram API.
Handle Player Authentication:
Players log in through Telegram. Use the telegram_id to identify users in your database.
Send Game Data Through the Bot:
Use the Telegram bot to send game updates (e.g., progress, inventory) as messages.
Interactive Gameplay:
Use inline keyboards, custom commands, or callback queries for game interactions.
Run the Game on Telegram:
Connect Web App to the Bot:
Use a Webhook or long polling to connect the bot to your Node.js server.
Token-Based Authentication:
Generate a unique token for each user session and validate it when connecting the bot to the web app.
Host the Game:
Deploy your app on a hosting platform and link it to the Telegram bot for seamless interaction.
